# static variable cpp do not want to change

Tags: c++, static-variables

```
FileA.hpp:

static int a; 
void change(int);

FileA.cpp

#include "FileA.hpp"
void change(int x) { a = x; }

main.cpp

#include "FileA.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    a = 5;
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
    change(10);
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
    a = 20;
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;

    system("Pause");

    return 0;
}
```

My output is:

```
5
5
20
```

Can someone help me with this? Why variable 'a' don't want to change in function
which is in FileA.cpp.
How to fix this. When I make change(int x) inline in "FileA.hpp" it works fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `static` keyword on a global variable gives that variable internal linkage. It means that any translation unit that has that definition will have its *own* copy of the object. So the `a` object that `main.cpp` sees and that `FileA.cpp` sees are different objects. `change` will modify one of them, but `main` will output the other.

If you were intending `static` to mean that the object has static storage duration, global variables (or variables at namespace scope in general) have static storage duration anyway. You don't need to mark them `static`. However, if you remove `static`, you'll have another problem; you'll have multiple definitions of `a` across translation units.

The correct way to do this is to declare `a` as `extern` in the `FileA.hpp` file:

```
extern int a;
```

Then in a single translation unit (probably in `FileA.cpp`, define the object:

```
int a;
```

This means that any object that includes `FileA.hpp` will have the declaration of `a` (which is fine) and only one translation unit will have the definition of `a`. Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You declare `a` in the header file, which when included creates two copies of it, one in `main.cpp` and one in `FileA.cpp`. When you do `a = 5;` you assign to the copy from main.cpp, while when calling the function `change`, it changes the copy in FileA.cpp.

Comment: good one, i was fooled the first time too. I'll be more careful with this kind of includes. your answer opened my eyes

Comment: You should probably stress the fact that this happens because `a` is declared `static`.